# ASP.Net MVC 3, Complex Objects and Lazy Loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, lazy-loading

First of all, I am new to ASP.Net MVC 3, and I am also using EF 4.1.

I have a complex object, something similar to let's say a Product object containing a Category object. So we have Product.CategoryId, Product.Category and some extra properties. I also have a form to create products with a dropdown list to select the category.

In my controller, after the product has been created, I need to have access to some property of the Category to perform some extra stuff. However, although Product.CategoryId is set, I cannot access Product.Category.SomeProperty because Product.Category is null. I expected Product.Category would be loaded automatically using some lazy loading, but it does not seem to be.

The code in my Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Products.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();

        string someString = product.Category.SomeProperty;
        ...
```

Now, this does not work because product.Category is null. What do I need to add so that I can access SomeProperty?

Comment: When you say "easy loading", I suspect you mean "lazy loading"

Comment: Uh! Yes... Sorry, still a bit tired on Sunday morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lazy loading will not work in this scenario because you are adding a new object. Lazy loading will work on "Proxy" entities created by EF context.

So what you can do here is [explicitly load](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) the navigational property.

```
    db.Products.Add(product);
    db.SaveChanges();

    db.Entry(product).Reference(p => p.Category).Load();

    string someString = product.Category.SomeProperty;
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Now, I have two extra questions. Is there a syntax to load many/all child objects, or do I have to repeat this command for every child I need? I noticed that db.Products.Include(p => p.Category).Load(); also works. What is the difference?

Comment: @Jean-François the article I linked in my answer explains in detail how `Load` and `Include` work. :)

Comment: Ok, I scanned it rapidly before, but I'll read it in details.

Comment: I read that document thoroughly, I tried many different things, but I haven't found how to load multiple level of children (children and grand-children) of a single object that has just been created. I posted an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239042/asp-net-mvc-3-how-do-you-load-children-and-grand-children-of-an-entity

If you ever have the answer to that one, a hint would be appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading doesn't work in your case because the `product` which is passed in into the controller action is not a proxy object but created as an ordinary `Product` instance by the model binder.

What you expect would work if `product` is created as a proxy:

```
var product = db.Products.Create();
product.CategoryId = 1;
db.Products.Add(product);
db.SaveChanges();

string someString = product.Category.SomeProperty;
// Category gets lazily loaded now
```

The `Category` property on the `Product` class must be `virtual` of course to have lazy loading working at all.

It doesn't help you in your situation because the model binder doesn't create a proxy.

Solutions: Either explicite loading (see @Eranga's answer) or in case you really only need to inspect the `SomeProperty` of the category fetch the value in a projection:

```
string someString = db.Entry(product).Reference(p => p.Category).Query()
    .Select(c => c.SomeProperty).SingleOrDefault();
```

...or (because you have the key of the category)...

```
string someString = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == product.CategoryId)
    .Select(c => c.SomeProperty).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is your last suggestion with the category key different from db.Categories.Find(product.CategoryId).Select(c => c.SomeProperty).SingleOrDefault(); ? Just checking whether this would lead to the same result for my personal knowledge.

Comment: @Jean-François: `db.Categories.Find(product.CategoryId).Select(c => c.SomeProperty).SingleOrDefault()` would not compile at all because `Find` returns a `Category` entity and not an `IQueryable<Category>`. `Find` always loads the full entity with all (scalar) properties. It's not suited for a projection into a single property or a set of seleted properties.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly enable lazy loading in your entity framework object context, as described in the MSDN article [How to: Use Lazy Loading to Load Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456846.aspx)

> In the Entity Framework runtime, the default value of the
>   LazyLoadingEnabled property in an instance of ObjectContext is false.

```
db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

More detail is provided in the [Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) article, just look in the section labeled "Lazily Loading Entity Objects".

Comment: In EF 4.1 lazy loading is [enabled by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.lazyloadingenabled(v=VS.103).aspx)

Comment: @Eranga That's true if you are using the EF tools to generate everything and then using those generated classes, but there are other ways to use EF; This is explained in the articles I linked to. It's unclear how the OP is using EF, hence I used the words "you may need to".

Comment: db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; did not help in this case.