# How to grab a property of a property object in DB

Tags: database, entity-framework, object, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for sometime now and I can't find any solution for my problem, even in this post:

[asp.net mvc 3 - How do you load children AND grand-children of an entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239042/asp-net-mvc-3-how-do-you-load-children-and-grand-children-of-an-entity)

Basically I have 3 classes:

Offer.cs, Application.cs, and Contractor.cs

1 Offer contains Collection of Aplications

1 Application contains 1 Contractor.

---

Basically I want to grab in the View the Contractor Object which is coming as null.
Thanks for any help!!!!

Here goes the code:

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
foreach (var candidate in item.Candidates)
    {
       Here is the problem #### canditate.Contractor == null ###
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index () {
 return View (db.Offers.Include(c => c.Location).Include(c => c.Candidates).ToList ());
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Offer {

public Location Location { get; set }
public ICollection<Application> Candidates { get; set; }

}

public class Application {
    public Contractor Contractor { get; set}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
db.Offers.Include("Location.Candidates").ToList()
```

This should load all the Locations and all the related Candidates for those Locations (although I do not know of a method to do this using lambdas).

Comment: Sorry I made a confusion when writting the post, I meant Contractor belongs to Application, not Location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

```
return View(db.Offers
    .Include(o => o.Location)
    .Include(o => o.Candidates.Select(c => c.Contractor))
    .ToList());
```

... in your `Index` action in order to load the `Contractor` grand children together with the `Candidates` children.